# Windows Azure Web Role to Upload File to Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-web-roles

I'm looking for an up-to-date tutorial or code sample showing how to create a web role which contains a field and button which allows the user to upload a file to Azure Blob Storage.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at this walk-through (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg651129.aspx) to get a feel on how to accomplish what you need. This is a console example, but, it should be trivial to translate it to a web based approach.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the very first hands-on lab in the Windows Azure [Platform Training Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8396), titled "Introduction to Windows Azure." This lab builds an ASP.NET MVC Guestbook application, which allows the end user to upload an image (which is then stored in Blob storage).